# Error during uploading an Play app to Heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework, typesafe-activator

first I'm new to Play. For my first steps I created a Play project by using the "Play Java Seed" provided by the typesafe activator tool. After I've created the projects and imported it into IntelliJ I'm trying to upload it to Heroku as shown here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/play-support. This is failing with the following log messages:

```
remote:        [info] downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/run-support_2.11/2.3.8/run-support_2.11-2.3.8.jar ...
remote:        [info]   [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.play#run-support_2.11;2.3.8!run-support_2.11.jar (229ms)
remote:        [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
remote:        [warn]   ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
remote:        [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
remote:        [warn]   :: com.typesafe.sbtrc#client-2-11;0.3.1: not found
remote:        [warn]   :: com.typesafe.sbtrc#actor-client-2-11;0.3.1: not found
remote:        [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
remote:        sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbtrc#client-2-11;0.3.1: not found
remote:        unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbtrc#actor-client-2-11;0.3.1: not found
remote:         at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:217)
remote:         at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:126)
```

If I start the app in the activator UI everything is fine. How can I fix the problem so I can upload the project to Heroku?

Answer (score 10):

It was the sbt-fork-run-plugin which was added by Activator. After adding the file to .gitignore everything works fine:

```
project/play-fork-run.sbt
```